# sql query - how to include columns in a group by query which are not in the "group by"?

Tags: sql

There are 2 tables involved in this question:

Table1:

```
PatientMaster:

PatientId,
PatientName
```

table2:

```
MedicineMaster:

MedicineId,
PatientId,
MedicineName
```

in table 2, many medicines with single patient is to be stored...

but i need only patientid and patientname from table 2..

my qry is,

```
select med.MedicineId,
       Pat.PatientName 
from medicinemaster as med 
  join PatientMaster as Pat on med.PatientId = Pat.PatientId 
group by Pat.PatientName
```

but Error came,

> Column 'medicinemaster.MedicineId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I a result like this:

```
PatientId  PatientName
3          xx
4          yy
```

Comment: What is the "question" you're trying to answer with this query?

Comment: table names in explanation and in query don't match

Comment: you can only use aggregated functions and fields from group by query. Show what do you need.

Comment: With those expected results, why do you even want the medicine table at all for this query?

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems that you are after patients' details who have some medicine. I would use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pat.PatientId, pat.PatientName
FROM
MedicineMaster med 
INNER JOIN PatientMaster pat ON pat.PatientId = med.PatientId
```

Since you are not using any kind of aggregation function (`sum`, `count`, `avg`, and so on) you don't need to group your data.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, GROUP BY actually need an aggregate function for the SQL parser to understand what you are trying to do.

I suggest you re-code the SQL to something like this ...

select Pat.PatientName,
       COUNT(med.MedicineId),
from medicinemaster as med 
join PatientMaster as Pat on med.PatientId = Pat.PatientId 
group by Pat.PatientName

Obviously that is not what you wanted, because the above SQL will now show you the PatientName and their MedicineID counts. If you want to see the actual IDs, then you need something like this ...

select Pat.PatientName,
       med.MedicineId,
       COUNT(*) as RowCount
from medicinemaster as med 
join PatientMaster as Pat on med.PatientId = Pat.PatientId 
group by Pat.PatientName, med.MedicineId

And the RowCount column will show you how many times the JOINs above created record complexes.

Comment: And as per Joel's answer below, you need to re-think your table structure.

Comment: You don't need an aggregate for `GROUP BY` without an aggregate it behaves the same as `DISTINCT`, the problem is fields in `SELECT` not in the `GROUP BY`, (well, works in MySQL but isn't the behavior sought by OP, I'd wager).

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information yet to answer your question.

But I can at least give you some help with your schema. The current schema design is wrong. You should have three tables:

**Table 1:**

> Patient (PatientID, PatientName)

**Table 2:**

> Medicine (MedicineID, MedicineName)

**Table 3:**

> PatientMedicines (MedicineID, PatientID)

Table three is called an *intersect table*, and they almost always end up as an entity in their own right, storing more data. In this case, you might re-name that table to something like "Prescription", and it might eventually store information such as the prescription date, expiration, prescribing doctor, dosage, etc.

And an update based on your edit: all you need right now is just:

```
SELECT PatientID, PatientName FROM Patients
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you don't actually need the MedicineMaster table.

But selecting *only* from the Patients table will also show you patients that have not (yet) got any medication. So if you want to see *only* patients that actually got a medicine you need to filter them out either by using an IN clause:

```
select PatientID, PatientName 
from Patients
where patientID in (select patientid 
                    from MedicineMaster);
```

or by using a co-related sub-query with an EXISTS predicate:

```
select p.PatientID, p.PatientName 
from Patients p
where exists (select 1
              from MedicineMaster m 
              where m.patientID = p.patientId);
```

There is no real difference between the two - most modern DBMS optimizers will generate the same execution plans (which means they will perform identically). If you are unlucky to be using MySQL you should use the second query as MySQL is terribly bad in optimizing `IN` queries.